# Increase the session timeout of my web form?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config, session-timeout

I need to increase session timeout of my web use form ...

could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <sessionState timeout="timeout in minutes"
       ...
  />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: But i couldnt see the session tag in web.config. But my webpage is timing out after some time.

Comment: SmartestVEGA: Add a `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="something" />` to `Web.config` if there's not one already. Note that "session timeout" is different from script timeout. If a single Web page is taking to long to display, it's not a session timeout. It's a script timeout.